# How do I avoid adding @using in my cshtml tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC with Razor.
I noticed that sometimes some cshtml files already have some namespaces imported (example for NopCommerce, which I am using to learn)

```
@model ProductListModel
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
```

Or

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml";

    Html.AppendScriptParts(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"));
    Html.AppendScriptParts(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js"));
    Html.AppendCssFileParts(@Url.Content("~/Content/Style/jquery.fileupload-ui.css"));
    Html.AppendCssFileParts(@Url.Content("~/Content/Style/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css"));
}
```

(Html.AppendScriptsParts is declared in the nop.Web.Framework.UI)
If I make my own cshtml file, I need to add the "using" line or reference with the like this:

```
@using System.Linq;
@using Nop.Web.Framework.UI

@model Nop.Admin.Models.Proposal.ProposalListModel
```

Is there any trick I am missing to reference these items? Why are the first 2 examples simpler and do not need the explicit reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add your namespace here `...\Views\Web.config`:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Your.Namespace" />  
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked on the webcfg located in the root folder, but not on the views one (didn't noticed it) thanks!