# C#: My 1st Azure DevOps Pipeline ("Hello, World!") - "The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

All I want (for now) is to create an Azure DevOps C# pipeline that runs `Helloworld.cs`.

I created a `Helloworld.cs` & `Helloworld.csproj` following [this Microsoft KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch?view=vs-2019).

**Helloworld.cs**

```
using System;

class HelloWorld
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

**Helloworld.csproj**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Helloworld.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Csc Sources="@(Compile)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I very slowly pieced together a YAML file following [this Microsoft KB (**"Build, test, and deploy .NET Core apps"**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) and [this one (**"YAML Schema Reference"**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#task).

When I tried to run the pipeline, the compiler for some reason seems to have a problem with the `System` namespace declaration in `Helloworld.cs` (which seems odd).

**Pipeline Output**

```
Helloworld.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\Helloworld.csproj]
Helloworld.cs(3,7): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [d:\a\1\s\Helloworld.csproj]
Helloworld.cs(5,9): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported [d:\a\1\s\Helloworld.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

So in my efforts to troubleshoot, I found this SO question:

[The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256896/the-type-or-namespace-name-system-could-not-be-found)

Some answers suggested restoring **NuGet** packages. So I followed [Microsoft's **NuGet [pipeline] task** documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) to add a NuGet restore as the first stage in my YAML.

**YAML File**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Restore_NuGet_Stage
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet Stage'
  jobs:
  - job: restore_nuget
    displayName: 'Restore NuGet'
    steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: restore
- stage: Build_Stage
  displayName: 'Build Stage'
  jobs: 
  - job: compile_cs
    displayName: 'Compile CS Files'
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build Task'
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: 'Helloworld.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration Testing'
```

But I still get the exact same `namespace name 'System' could not be found` errors found above.

What must I fix to get past this error? I thought just compiling the code was going to be the easy part...

**EDIT** - Here's the preliminary output shown when I run the pipeline. There's `.Net Core version 2.158.1` listed & `SDK Version 3.0.100`, in case that helps

```
Starting: Build Task
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.158.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\Helloworld.csproj --configuration Testing

Welcome to .NET Core 3.0!
---------------------
SDK Version: 3.0.100
```

Comment: where do yu get this error? in visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference for creating a project file is quite out of date - this goes back to the days where there was only one .net framework so msbuild didn't need to be told what the target was.

Nowadays, there's an additional configuration element required to tell msbuild what framework you're using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj

You will need to add a TargetFramework property:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Without this, the compiler doesn't know where "System" is, because [dotnet core is based on metapackages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/packages)

Additionally, building dotnet core projects also requires the Sdk property to be specified - when I generate a default empty console project with `dotnet new console`, I get:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Note the `Sdk=` attribute at the root level. This is documented on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2019):

> MSBuild 15.0 introduced the concept of the "project SDK", which simplifies using software development kits that require properties and targets to be imported.

[I stumbled on a decent-looking blog article](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) which summarises the changes needed to upgrade an old .net framework project to dotnet core - the long and the short of it is that your problems are being caused by mixing an old project format with new tooling. To build a .Net Framework project, I think you will need the [msbuild pipeline task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) and not the dotnet cli task.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same errors after adding `<PropertyGroup><TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework></PropertyGroup>` in-between the `<Project>` tags. I also tried changing `2.1` to `3.0` as well to no avail

Comment: Was on my phone before; am at a PC now, will try and reproduce.

Comment: So the only change needed was indeed the `.csproj` file--just putting in the default contents like you've got here...I thought many times of just starting a new C# project in VS to see what the contents of the `.csproj` were & copy them over to my pipeline's `.csproj`...Looks like I should have just done that lol