# C# Using System imports have errors

Tags: c#, import, syntax-error, system, using

I forked a repository from GitHub because I was trying to make my own changes to it. When I open up rider, there are errors everywhere. For some reason, the import statements are not working or erroring out in someway.

The image is showing that it can not resolve a symbol called System. It is then telling me it is not necessary in the code and it should be removed.
[image]

When I tried running dotnet restore in VS 2019 Developer Command Prompt, it tells me that none of the projects contained packages to restore.

[Screenshot of the error I mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXM5f.png)

Also just for clarification, I forked a project from github that can send text to a discord webhook and I am trying to edit it for more functionality.

Answer: I tried some of the suggestions but none seemed to work so I made a new project and copied the code. That ended up working.

Comment: Have you tried opening a developer command prompt, navigating to the solution directory and running the command: `dotnet restore`?

Comment: can you explain more ? is it a dot net core application ?

Comment: I tried running dotnet restore with the vs 2019 dev cmd and it states that there are no packages to restore. I will add a screenshot to the post

Comment: @MohsenZahedi
I am not sure if it is a dot net core application or not. I edited my post to show that I forked a repo to add more functionality to it. I can tell you some of the files that are in it if that may help you?

Assemblyinfo.cs
App.config
And then in rider there are two folders called imports and assemblies which contain the system files and the c#. Also, I noticed that Assembly for system is yellow as in hazard. Is this normal?
https://imgur.com/a/XyJOOWt

Comment: It couldn't be normal .seems there is a VS problem so I suggest you refer to  
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256896/the-type-or-namespace-name-system-could-not-be-found

Comment: I use rider but it should not make a difference. Anyway, I tried some of the steps in the post you sent but I still could not figure it out so I made a new project and I copied the code. For some reason that worked. @MohsenZahedi

Comment: Don't worry ,these problems in dot net will be happen.

Comment: @MohsenZahedi Thanks for your attempt at helping.

Comment: Glad to help you.